# Unable to receive correct message in Quickblox

Tags: quickblox

When I execute the [sample chat program](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample) in quickblox, I expect
chatRoom to process the received message: expecting  **hello** from user 
Michael Soong. Instead the app shows that the message, it shows a sender 
with a number and a body string of the following:

02-24 12:25:22.616: D/RoomChat(27962): sender = 883016

02-24 12:25:22.616: D/RoomChat(27962): body = 
{\22message\22\3a\22hello\22,\22name\22\3a\22Michael\20Soong\22,\22avatar\22\3anull,\22fb\22\3anull}

Comment: Is it this user message ?